# How to/do I need to remove adhesive from old tiles before placing new?

Tags: flooring

Updating the flooring in a small bathroom with "luxury" peel and stick vinyl flooring. After starting to remove the old vinyl tile flooring, there is an INCREDIBLY sticky later of glue left behind (and on the old tiles).

Wondering how I can remove it or "neutralize" it somehow. The idea of removing it with solvents or neutralizint it with something dry sounds questionable because I'm worried it would end up making the NEW peel and stick vinyl tile adhesive less effective.

Thanks in advance.

[image: sticky tiles]

[image: floor 2]

Comment: if it's so sticky, and you want the new floor to stick, why remove it?

Comment: That's a question I had as well. Aside from making it difficult to move around the room, I was worried there could be some unwanted reaction/interaction between the new adhesive and the old that would risk the integrity of the new install.

Comment: How many tiles have you removed? You need to put them back and encapsulate the floor. There are a few methods. Please post pics of current floor and I’ll will write an answer for your specific situation.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the top layer of tiles (the white tiles) do not contain asbestos. I am not removing or disturbing the second (bottom, brown/tan stripped) layer of tiles, which look like they are original and likely contain asbestos.

Comment: There is an EPA regulation that requires a chain-of-custody for asbestos flooring.. By law, you need to encapsulate that floor with a minimum, 1/4” plywood. Cover the floor up, do not remove the tiles.

Comment: If the floor tile is not disturbed that is not true. You're not reading thoroughly - the old (possible asbestos) tile is being covered by new vinyl flooring - again, not being removed. As long as it remains in stable condition, that is entirely adequate.